# File Size Validation

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, filesize

Im trying to upload a file of particular extensions and of limited size.

Extension part is done using RegularExpression Validator but still left with the File Size restrictions.

File Size limit is **500KB** and i want to validate the **file size before i press submit button** to upload the file on the server.